# Once an inline Chrome app is installed, how do you run it?

Tags: google-chrome-app

Once an inline Chrome app is installed, ie `chrome.webstore.install(undefined,success(),fail()); // where success() is called` ... how do you have the website automatically run the app?

Similarly, if `chrome.app.isInstalled==true` how do you have the website run the app?

Comment: Are you asking exclusively for Chrome OS? I assumed that this was related to chrome browser, in any OS. Sergey's answer should work if you only need this working on Chrome OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are launching it from an extension, use chrome.management.launchApp:

[chrome.management API for chrome extensions https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#method-launchApp](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#method-launchApp)

Edit: At this point I don't know of any way to launch a chrome packaged app using javascript other than the above. If you inspect the chrome object in the console you'll see that neither the chrome.app or the chrome.webstore objects provide any launching methods for installed apps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your app [externally_connectable](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/externally_connectable.html) and grant your website permission to connect.
2. In the website's code, use [chrome.runtime.sendMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime.html#method-sendMessage) (or [chrome.runtime.connect](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime.html#method-connect) in case you need a more involved communication channel) to send commands to your app.
3. In the app's event page, add a [chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime.html#event-onMessageExternal) listener to process commands from the website. From there, you can call chrome.app.window.open() just as you would from an onLaunched listener.